# How to calculate how circular the blob is using Open CV - SimpleBlobDetector()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have two images of moles. One is relatively round but the other isn't. I want to find out how circular the mole is say -1 being not at all circular,0 being elliptical, and 1 being circular. I first converted the raw image into binary and then tried using the code below. The code draws a circle around the circular mole but doesn't give information on inertia. The non-cricular mole is not even detected as a blob. Am I understanding this concept incorrectly? How should I go about solving this problem?

[image: circular non-edited mole][image: Circular edited Mole][image: non circular non-edited mole][image: Non-Circular edit Mole]

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10;
params.maxThreshold = 200;

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 1500

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("mole_torezo.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the     circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]),         (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks to [Blob Detection Using OpenCV ( Python, C++ )](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) for the code

Comment: Can you post both images, without any processing?

Comment: @Zindarod done!

Comment: You're using the exact same code as shown on the link you post. Did you try changing any of the parameters? For example, I could think that lowering `minConvexity` would allow you to detect less convex shapes, as in your second example.

Comment: I guess I wanted a code that could detect all the blobs but give information on the convexity, inertia and circularity of the blob. I am still working on building that code. And you are right. I didn't realize early that the parameters were acting as a filter rather than what I wanted in my case.